# query is not giving desired result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have date format issue.
Below is my query.
Query is executing but without result.

```
SELECT a,b,c,DATE_FORMAT(Date_Rx_Written,'%m-%d-%Y') AS 'Date Rx Written',e,f,g,h 
FROM ksclient1003.prescriber_view 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Date_Rx_Written,'%m-%d-%Y')
BETWEEN coalesce(NULLIF('11-11-2008',' '),Date_RX_Written)
AND coalesce(NULLIF('11-11-2016',' '),Date_RX_Written) 
AND a=coalesce(NULLIF('Genene Radden',' '),a) 
AND b=coalesce(NULLIF('Filled',' '),b);
```

if i execute in parts it is working fine like,

```
SELECT a,b,c,DATE_FORMAT(Date_Rx_Written,'%m-%d-%Y') AS 'Date Rx Written',e,f,g,h
FROM ksclient1003.prescriber_view;
```

or simply excluding date filter.

```
SELECT a,b,c,DATE_FORMAT(Date_Rx_Written,'%m-%d-%Y') AS 'Date Rx Written',e,f,g,h
FROM ksclient1003.prescriber_view 
WHERE a=coalesce(NULLIF('Genene Radden',' '),a)
AND b=coalesce(NULLIF('Filled',' '),b);
```

i have tried different approach like changing format every place where i am simply passing Date_RX_Written.

Note :

Comment: try `SELECT a,b,c,DATE_FORMAT(Date_Rx_Written,'%m-%d-%Y') AS 'Date Rx Written',e,f,g,h 
FROM ksclient1003.prescriber_view 
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(Date_Rx_Written,'%m-%d-%Y')
BETWEEN coalesce(NULLIF('11-11-2008',' '),Date_RX_Written)
AND coalesce(NULLIF('11-11-2016',' '),Date_RX_Written))
AND a=coalesce(NULLIF('Genene Radden',' '),a) 
AND b=coalesce(NULLIF('Filled',' '),b);` put BETWEEN clause in brackets

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT 
   a, b, c, 
   DATE_FORMAT(Date_Rx_Written,'%m-%d-%Y') as 'Date Rx Written',
   e,f,g,h 
FROM ksclient1003.prescriber_view 
WHERE 
   Date_Rx_Written BETWEEN '2008-11-11' AND '2016-11-11' 
   AND a='Genene Radden' 
   AND b='Filled';
```

Comment: no luck..
and i want to handle null values so with coalesce it is not useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution..

```
select a,b,c,DATE_FORMAT(Date_Rx_Written,"%m-%d-%Y") as 'Date Rx Written'  ,d,e,f,g from ksclient1003.prescriber_view  WHERE Date_Rx_Written BETWEEN coalesce(NULLIF(STR_TO_DATE('31-12-2014' , "%d-%m-%Y"),' ')) and coalesce(NULLIF(STR_TO_DATE('31-12-2016' , "%d-%m-%Y"),' ')) and a=coalesce(NULLIF('Genene Radden',' '),a) and b=coalesce(NULLIF('Filled',' '),b);
```